# Finding numbers in a list and replacing with another

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers that I want to replace with their word versions.

This is the code I have so far:

```
phone_num = fixPhoneNum(original) # 067-892-3451
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
             'eight', 'nine']

    a = list(phone_num)
    for n,i in (a):
    if i==1:
        a[n]=words[1] # etc..
```

How would I go about replacing the numbers from one list with another?

**Edit** I completed the translation from number to words, but the words have no spaces between them ex. twosixeight-etc..

How can I make it so each word ends with a space? Do I insert and space after each in the words list?

Answer (score 1):

Try this let me know how it goes

```
phone_num = fixPhoneNum(original) # 067-892-3451
def getWordForm(phone_num):
    words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
             'eight', 'nine']
a = list(phone_num)
for n,i in (a):
if i==1:
    a[n]=words[1]+' '
```

Comment: That works! I was going to add spaces to the elements in the words list, but this is much nicer to look at.

Comment: @SaigonoAkuma glad I could help , mark as answer :)

Comment: But, now there's no spaces in front of the hyphens ex. six four one -eight nine zero. How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: @SaigonoAkuma how are the hyphens coming? It is not there in the words list

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map` and `lambda` to achieve similar job.

```
phone_num = fixPhoneNum(original) # 067-892-3451
words = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven',
    'eight', 'nine']
num_in_words = map(lambda num: words[int(num)] if num.isdigit() else num, phone_num)
print (''.join(num_in_words))
```

Output

```
 zerosixseven-eightninetwo-threefourfiveone
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example #1** — Tested with Python ***2.6.9*** and ***2.7.10*** and ***3.2.5*** and ***3.4.3*** and ***3.5.0***

```python
def getWordForm(original):
    a = []
    words = 'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine'.split(',')
    for i in original:
        a.append(words[int(i)]) if i.isdigit() else a.append(i)
    return ' '.join(a)

print(getWordForm('067-892-3451'))
```

**Output**

```
zero six seven - eight nine two - three four five one
```

**Working Example #2** — Tested with Python ***2.6.9*** and ***2.7.10*** and ***3.2.5*** and ***3.4.3*** and ***3.5.0***

```python
def getWordForm(original):
    words = 'zero,one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine'.split(',')
    a = map(lambda num: words[int(num)] if num.isdigit() else num, original)
    return ' '.join(a)

print(getWordForm('067-892-3451'))
```

**Output**

```
zero six seven - eight nine two - three four five one
```